# How to ignore a jar in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a dependency (external library) in my `build.gradle` that performs some health check to see if our Kafka connectors are working correctly so the app is `UP` when we do a `'/actuator/health'`.

Now we are doing load tests and I want to ignore those health checks so that the pod in Kubernetes is `READY` even if I don't setup a Kafka broker

How can I ignore a jar with spring boot ?

Answer (score 0):

You can set application.properties to disable it.

```
management.endpoints.enabled-by-default=false
```